# How can I animate a recently created DOM element in the same function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working to create an image gallery where the images will be composed by progressively fading in layers one on top of the other to form the final image.

I have many such layers so instead of loading them into many different `<img>` elements all at once (which would slow load time) I want to start off with a single `<img id="base">` and then **progressively add image elements** with the jQuery `.after()` method, assign them the relevant sources and fade them in with a delay.

The problem is that I can't attach animations to the newly created elements because (I'm assuming) they don't exist yet within the same function. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="gallery">
  <img id="base" src="image-1.jpg">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#base { 
    opacity: 0;
    }
.layers {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    }
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#base").animate({opacity: 1}, 300); //fade in base
    for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfLayers; i++, gap += 300) {
        // create a new element
        $("#base").after("<img class='layers' src='" + imgName + ".png'>");
        // fade that new element in
        $("#gallery").children().eq(i).delay(gap).animate({opacity: '1'}, 300);
    }
}
```

Please note that I've altered my actual code to illustrate this better. I'm fairly new at JavaScript but I'm a quick learner so I'd appreciate if you could tell me what I'm doing wrong and what solution I should pursue.

Comment: Can you provide a demo on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Vohuman yes, hope [this](http://jsfiddle.net/johnnymates/m8m0eL3v/1/) helps

Comment: @IonMates hope [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pgoevx03/1/) helps... I looked at your updated fiddle and figured out what was wrong with what I initially suggested.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I've included my code inside your JSFiddle (all you need to do is add the library-X.jpg images) : http://jsfiddle.net/pgoevx03/

---

I've tried to replicate the intent of the code in a cleaner/more flexible way. Please let me know if I can do anything else to help.

I'm not saying this is the best way to do it, but it should be easy enough to understand and use.

**The code is untested, but should work just fine.** The comments should help you out if there's any compilation error.

Note that I removed the first image in the gallery (with ID "base") from the HTML file. It will be appended the same way as the rest.

```
// Array storing all the images to append to the gallery
var galleryImages = [
    "image-1.jpg",
    "image-2.jpg",
    "image-3.jpg",
    "image-4.jpg",
    "image-5.jpg",
    "image-6.jpg",
    "image-7.jpg",
    "image-8.jpg",
    "image-9.jpg",
    "image-10.jpg"
];

// Index of the image about to be appended
var imgIndex = -1;

var baseID = "base";


$(document).ready(function() {
    // Start appending images
    appendAllImages();
});


// Append the images, one at a time, at the end of the gallery
function appendAllImages() {

    //Move to the next image
    imgIndex++;

    //We've reached the last image: stop appending
    if (imgIndex >= galleryImages.length) return;



    //Create image object
    var img = $("<img>", {
        src: galleryImages[imgIndex],
    });

    if (imgIndex === 0) { // It's the base!

        //Give the base ID to the first image
        img.attr("id", baseID);

        //Append the image object
        $("#gallery").append(img);


    } else { // It's a layer!

        //Give the base ID to the first image
        img.attr("class", "layers");

        //Append the image object
        $("#" + baseID).after(img);

    }

    //Fade in the image appended; append the next image once it's done fading in
    img.animate({
        opacity: 1,
    }, 300, appendAllImages);

}
```